# How do I build a script that automatically sends out emails?

Tags: email

So I've done some research on the topic, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the emails to send. This is the sheet I've been using: https://docs.google.com/a/taktical.co/spreadsheets/d/18GsFLLUCCAba82Teyd4nI8XSuNwEBvunjpQeNdYY-6U/edit#gid=0

I want to be able to pull the information from the first sheet, and have the recipient email set to Contact Email 1. I also need an if statement that says if any cell in row D says "not found", to just simply not send the email.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you need to give some more information with regards to your research. What language should this be done with? What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I dont have any preference with the language as long as it can run in Google Sheet's script editor. I've tried using the code google provided but it seems to only send me back error messages. All I need is a script that can use the email address in column D and send it out using the template on the second tab.

Answer (score 0):

I splitted your problem into 3 distinct areas, with suggestions on how to solve it.

1. Consider using the [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) API to read the data from your Google Doc into a [Python script](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/).
2. Then to send email with Python, see [Python Documentation: Email examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html).
3. Finally, to automatically run this Python script it kind of depends on which OS you are using. In Linux you could set it up as a [cronjob](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) or just autostart it to run all the time.

I hope this will get you somewhere.